# How to drop rows with respect to a column values in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wantto remove rows with respect `ID` column values.

> df

```
   ID    B   C   D
0  101   1   2   3
1  103   5   6   7
2  108   9  10  11
3  109   5   3  12
4  118  11  15   2
5  121   2   5   6
```

Here the `remove_id` list of `ID` value those I want to remove.

```
remove_id = [103,108, 121]
```

I want to output like following:

> df

```
   ID    B   C   D
0  101   1   2   3
3  109   5   3  12
4  118  11  15   2
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check which IDs are in `remove_id` with the `isin` method, negate the result with `~` and use the resulting `Series` for boolean indexing.

```
>>> df[~df['ID'].isin(remove_id)]
>>> 
    ID   B   C   D
0  101   1   2   3
3  109   5   3  12
4  118  11  15   2
```

Details:

```
>>> df['ID'].isin(remove_id)
>>> 
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
Name: ID, dtype: bool
>>> ~df['ID'].isin(remove_id)
>>> 
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
Name: ID, dtype: bool
```